# Max simultaneous clicks a website can handle?

Tags: html, web

I want to develop a website that ultimately will be used on a touchscreen device, allowing multiple users to take advantage of gestures such as pinch-zoom and so forth. Is there a default maximum  number of touches a website can handle? To be clear, this is one instance of a webpage, not a webpage served multiple times.

Comment: It's probably not a matter of the maximum *events* the website can handle, but rather, that your JavaScript code can only ever have one thread.

Comment: Are you saying that multiple users will be utilising the same instance of the web page? That seems like an unusual circumstance if so